# SQL Server 2008 group by and order by to get sort list of most paid to least paid

Tags: sql-server

Below is my query in this I am getting data the customer paid most to least paid.

But the problem is suppose customer A is paid most one and it repeats 3 to 4 records with customer A like if have lot of customers.

I need customer A high payment to least payment and after that a customer most to least payment like that.

Need to include group by customer not able to do.

```
select  
    a.custcode, a.dono, b.dolnno, b.item, b.itemdesc,
    isnull(a.ordertype,'') ordertype,
    a.custname, a.CollectionDate,
    CAST((SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 7, 4) + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 4, 2) + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 1, 2)) AS date) AS trandate,
    isnull(a.jobnum,'') jobnum, 
    isnull(a.Remark1,'') as remarks,
    b.lnstat, isnull(b.qtyor,0) qtyor, 
    isnull(b.qtypick, 0) qtypick, isnull(b.qtyis, 0) qty, 
    isnull(b.unitprice, 0) unitprice, b.crat, 
    ISNULL(qtyor * b.unitprice, 0) ordPrice, 
    ISNULL(qtyis * b.unitprice, 0) issPrice,
    isnull(deliverydate, '') deliverydate,
    isnull(timeslots, '') deliverytime,
    isnull(c.prd_brand_id, '') as prd_brand_id,
    isnull(c.prd_cls_id, '') as prd_cls_id,
    isnull(c.itemtype, '') as itemtype,
    isnull(a.status_id, '') as status_id,
    isnull(a.OUTBOUND_GST, 0) as Tax
from 
    [test_dohdr] a,[test_dodet] b,[test_ITEMMST]c 
where 
    a.dono = b.dono 
    and b.ITEM = c.item   
    and ISNULL(CollectionDate, '') <> '' 
    AND CAST((SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 7, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 1, 2)) AS date) >= '2014-05-01'   
    and ISNULL(CollectionDate, '') <> ''
    AND CAST((SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 7, 4) + '-' + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 4, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(a.CollectionDate, 1, 2)) AS date) <= '2015-05-07'  
order by 
    (qtyis * b.unitprice) DESC
```

Comment: can you add expected output

Comment: Also don't store dates as characters. [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: And furthermore: try to be **consistent** with your keywords - *either* write **ALL** of them in all uppercase (`SELECT`, `ISNULL`, `CASE`) - or then write them all in lowercase (`select`, `isnull`,  `case`) - just don't do this crazing mixing that you have going .....

Comment: If we're talking standards here, we can also take a look at the naming standards. status_id, prd_cls_id. These are bad. You should use PascalCase to name your columns, and not use underscores, also they should be descriptive. 'status_id' could mean anything, since everything has a status and an identity. 'prd_cls_id' is shortened, why? That's old style naming back when we could only use 8 character naming styles. I call it 'tibbling'. Looking at this it seems that the CollectionDate is probably an existing column not created by the OP, hence why he's casting it back to `DATETIME`.

Comment: Customer 1 2400000
CONDEMN 2400
Customer 1 400
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 200
Customer 1 100
Customer 1 100
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 80
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 16
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 6
But I need Data like:

Comment: Customer 1 2400000
Customer 1 400
Customer 1 400
Customer 1 100
Customer 1 100
CONDEMN 2400
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 200
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 80
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 16
AMO SINGAPORE PTE LTD 6
This is what i want.

Comment: Thanks all for your advises. This data base design done few years back now i cant change design. Further more i can try to be consistent.